# Blogger image with caption was not resize to fit the width

Tags: css, image, resize, blogger, captions

I am using responsive theme on My website and i have this problem on small size screens, like mobile and tablets.

It's work correctly with the image which is NOT have CAPTION

All the Images with caption are displaying origional Size on mobiles.

I already tried

```
.tr-caption-container{
max-width:100%; height: auto;
}
```

but not working.
Any suggestion??
My website is http://www.mysteryofindia.com/

Comment: can you be more specific? Where is the problem located? I'm not seeing the issue

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
.tr-caption-container img{
max-width:100%; height: auto;
}
```

Comment: I tried but not working. I partially fixed the problem enabling Mobile version of BLOG.